# Rails 4: How to define a constraint for string param containing dots in routes.rb the DRY way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, constraints

How to draw a route with an IPv4 address as param. Just like this:

**`http://localhost:3000/ip/192.168.2.2`**

This route should only be used if `request.params[:ipaddress]` is an IPv4 address, but all I get is: `No route matches [GET] "/ip/192.168.2.2"`

---

#### First try: constraints: { ipaddress: /^regexp$/ }

Defining the constraint expression inline in `.config/routes.rb` like this:

```rb
resources :ipaddresses, path: :ip, param: :ipaddress, constraints: {
  ipaddress: /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/ }, only: :show
```

leads to an error and the server does not start:

> /home/mschmidt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:207:in
>
> `verify_regexp_requirement': Regexp **anchor characters** are not allowed in routing requirements

---

#### Second try: without anchor characters

If I remove the anchor characters the server does start, but the constraint does not express what is wanted. The string can contain **one or more** IPv4 addresses, now.

---

#### Third try: move it to a function

So, I put the expression into a class with a method called `matches?`. This works perfect if the param does not have any dot. Unfortunately all these IPs have some dots and I'm back where I started:

`No route matches [GET] "/ip/192.168.2.2"`

/config/routes.rb:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  class IPv4Constraint
    def matches?(request)
      request.params[:ipaddress] =~ /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/
    end 
  end 
  
  resources :ipaddresses, path: :ip, param: :ipaddress, constraints: IPv4Constraint.new, only: :show
end
```

---

Because of the dots I have to define a constraint in routes.rb anyways and I think it wouldn't be very DRY to put more code for this into the controller. What is the best way to do this? Is there even a way to do this with a single expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use [routing-filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter) for now.

After adding the gem to the Gemfile:
`gem 'routing-filter'`

I added a new filter:

```
# The IPv4Address filter extracts segments matching /ip/:IPv4Address from the
# end of the recognized url and exposes the page parameter as
# params[:ipv4address]. When a url is generated the filter adds the address to
# the url accordingly if the page parameter is passed to the url helper.
#
#   incoming url: /ip/192.168.2.2
#   filtered url: /ip
#   generated url: /ip/192.168.2.2
#
# You can install the filter like this:
#
#   # in config/routes.rb
#   Rails.application.routes.draw do
#     filter :ipv4address
#   end
module RoutingFilter
  class Ipv4address < Filter
    IPV4ADDRESS_PATTERN = %r(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$)

    def around_recognize(path, env, &block)
      pattern = pattern_builder(path)
      ipv4address = extract_segment!(pattern, path)
      yield.tap do |params|
        params[:ipv4address] = ipv4address if ipv4address
      end
    end

    def around_generate(params, &block)
      ipv4address = params.delete(:ipv4address)
      yield.tap do |result|
        append_segment!(result, "ip/#{ipv4address}") if append_ipv4address?(ipv4address)
      end
    end

    private

    def pattern_builder(path)
      ipv4address = extract_ipv4address(path)
      build = "/(#{ipv4address.gsub('.','\.')})/?$"
      /#{build}/
    end

    def extract_ipv4address(path)
      path.match(IPV4ADDRESS_PATTERN).to_s
    end

    def append_ipv4address?(ipv4address)
      ipv4address && !ipv4address.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

called it in routes.rb and changed the action from `show` to `index`

> filter :ipv4address
>
> resources :ipaddresses, path: :ip, only: :index

The IP is now available in my controller as `params[:ipv4address]`